# Trigonometric differentiation

Tags: derivatives

I haven't use derivatives in a long time and I'm having some difficulty remembering them. Can someone explain the derivative below?

$\frac{d}{dt}\sin\theta(t)= \frac{d(\sin\theta)}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$

What rule is applied here?

Comment: The chain rule.

Comment: Well, it's nonsense as you typed it. Presumably you *meant* to type $$\frac{d(\sin\theta)}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}.$$

Comment: Yep it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, this is an example of the chain rule.

The chain rule states:

$$F'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$$

In this case, $\sin(\theta)$ would be $f$ and $\theta(t)$ would be $g$